# Detect change, if input-text is changed by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, event-handling, onchange

Summary- I am working on a text-comparison tool. I have two functions 
- an excel-parser, which fetches data from excel file and changes the input-text dynamically/programmatically.
- a text comparison function listens for any changes in the input field and runs text-comparison logic.

I am new to jQuery but have tried JS with eventListeners, oninput, onchange, onpaste, etc.
Note: The following code snippet explains the situation. However, there is no such button click.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("test");

function assignValue() {
  a.value = "Hello World";
}
a.addEventListener('input', recInput);

function recInput() {
  console.log("Sucess!");
}
```

```html
<input id="test">
<button onclick="assignValue()">Click to add text</button>
```

Is there any way of capturing changes using JS? If not, I am open to using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to do this.

Register a callback function that will deal with the changing attribute.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('name');
const observer = new MutationObserver(list => {
  console.log("New Value: ", list[0].target.value);
})
observer.observe(input, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: false,
  subtree: false
});

function changeIt() {
  const randomString = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? "one" : "two";
  input.setAttribute("value", randomString);
  input.value = randomString;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" id="name" />
<button onclick='changeIt()'>Push me
</button>
```

You'll need to use `setAttribute()` and you'll need to set the Input element's `value` property to keep it in sync with the attribute. (as seen in the `changeIt()` function.

Comment: Thanks @Randy the solution also worked with multiple observers registered to same callback Function!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [onkeydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown) for this.

```
var a = document.getElementById("test");

a.addEventListener('onkeydown', recInput);

function recInput(e) {
  console.log("Sucess!", e.key);
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to capture a programatic change to the `HTMLInputElement`, not a keyboard entry. This doesn't answer the question.