# How to know when a given element has been connected to the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, dom-events

**Core question**

Suppose you have a DOM Element `e`, which is disconnected from current `document`, i.e.

```
document.compareDocumentPosition(e) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED
```

is `true`.

How to tap into an event that triggers at the moment (or next tick, it doesn't matter) this node gets connected, i.e.

```
document.compareDocumentPosition(e) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED
```

starts returning `false`?

**Higher context**

I have an angular component whose `ngAfterViewInit` will compute some values given the current element style (actual dimensions, paddings, margins and so on).

But angular is free to call `ngAfterViewInit` after its descendants have been created, but not necessarilly connected to its parent. An element disconnected from the document has essentially no style, so every dimension is - reasonably - zero.

I want to postpone this computation until this element gets finally connected to the whole document, CSS rules get applied, HTML/CSS is reflowed and the element's style settles.

**The MutationObserver failure**

I've tried to use a MutationObserver, this way:

```
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            console.log('got mutations', mutations);
            mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (node === this.element) {
                        console.log('GOT CONNECTED');
                    }
                })
            });
        }).observe(document, { childList: true });
    });
```

Not even the first "got mutations" has shown up in console. Maybe I've got something wrong. I'm new to this `MutationObserver` thing.

Comment: Use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - see a sample (not exact use case) here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159513/detect-change-if-input-text-is-changed-by-javascript/56159793#56159793

Comment: @RandyCasburn I've tried, to no avail. I'll edit the question to show what I've done.

Comment: Put up a simple Blitz so we can get you fixed up.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'll try. But it'll take a while before I can find a MCVE. I'll come back here in a day or 2 and post the link.

Comment: If you're confident `this.element` is correct, you need to add `subtree: true` to your init object. Otherwise the observation won't cascade. And THAT, is a problem. Please consider setting your observer on the deapest part of the tree possible and NOT the document.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-op7naf

Comment: @RandyCasburn no no, not the template; a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the behavior I'm getting. I can't put all of my system in stackblitz (not accounting for a breach of contract of publishing otherwise private and confidential work, the code alone would be 2.5Mb and unecessarily complex).

Comment: @RandyCasburn `this.element` is correct: the member field which holds a reference to current `elementRef`'s `nativeElement`. Actually, the code didn't even reach that point, so no worries about that.

Comment: Also, at this point (`ngAfterViewInit`), besides the components own element, the only other element I know of is `document`, so no alternatives where I can attach the `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Sounds like your component is doing work that should be done via CSS to me.